# Pascal - Greatest Common Divisor - No Output

Tags: pascal

Thank you for all help in advance. I have to start programming in Pascal and to e quite honest it's not all that pleasant change from Java and Python. I tried a simple program to return GCD, but console won't even stay open despite the readln at the end.

```
program App1Learning;

var
  a, b : integer;

begin
  read(a);
  read(b);
  while a <> b do
  begin
    if a < b then b := b - a;
    if a > b then a := a - b;
  end;
  writeln(a);
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: I tried debugging by adding writelns everywhere and somehow managed to fix it by adding a readln after reading the arguments... I just don't understand any of this...

      read(a);
      read(b);
      readln;

Comment: `Read(A)` will read one number but not advance to the next line. I'd rather use `Readln(A)`, to get one number per line. This is different than in Java, but I don't find the Java way very intuitive either.

Comment: Which Pascal are you using? FreePascal, Delphi, GNU Pascal, what? There are differences, especially in the more advanced features.

Comment: Even if the read/write issue is corrected, this will **hang** for e.g. `a = -4, b=2` with `gcd(a,b)=2`. You should use `abs`.

Comment: In Free Pascal, your program works fine even without the `readln`.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing which Pascal you are using, I tried this in FreePascal 3.0.0 for Windows:

```
program App1Learning;

var
  a, b : integer;

begin
  readln(a);
  readln(b);
  // Or, instead of the two previous lines: readln(a, b);
  while a <> b do
  begin
    if a < b then b := b - a;
    if a > b then a := a - b;
  end;
  writeln(a);
  readln;
end.
```

`Read()`, while it depends on buffered line input, does not wait for a carriage return, so it will read two numbers but **not consume the final carriage return, i.e. this is still in the input buffer**. After the program calculates the GCD and displays it, the carriage return that is still in the buffer will be immediately read by the final `readln`, so the console closes right afterward (`readln` doesn't have to wait for a carriage return, as it is already — or still — in the buffer).

If you use `readln(a);` etc. instead, each number will be input on its own line and the function waits for a carriage return and consumes it. This means that the final `readln` will not find a carriage return in the input buffer, so it will wait until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I use Lazarus. The problem is that when I use read(a,b) or read(a); read(b); the console just pops out every time. I tried to put inputs in one and separate lines in both cases. No luck. However when I use readline, either for a,b or separately, it just works, no problems at all. I don't really get where's the catch. Even if there was a fault, I have a readln at the end, so why does it quit just like that? No exception, nothing. Just... poof.

Comment: @SamuelNovelinka: as I said, if you use `Read()`, the newline is left in the buffer, ready to be consumed by the final `Readln`. This means that `Readln` doesn't have to wait for you to press enter and the console window closes immediately. **In other words, if you use `Read`, the final `Readln` already finds a carriage return in the buffer and does not wait for one anymore.**

Comment: Oh, I get it know. Thank you a lot. Would that mean that a second readln right after would do the trick? I know it sounds somehow amateur-ish, and I don't intend to use it, just want to make sure I got it right.

Comment: Yes, a second `Readln` would do the trick too. Or simply: `read(a); readln(b)` or `readln(a, b);`. Then you could enter the numbers on the same line and the final `readln`would not find a newline in the buffer.